# xConnect error NotSupportedException GetDataCurrentlyIndexedToken

Tags: xconnect

I'm seeing a pattern of errors in ApplicationInsights in Azure, repeated approximately every 30 seconds.

[image: Application insights]

At point in time analytics data was being collected, but for several days no new visit data has appeared. It is likely a configuration change caused a problem but I'm yet to narrow down what that was.

The custom event has a RenderedMessage Batch Execution Failed "XdbContextLoggingPlugin"

**Exception Properties**

**Event time**  18/07/2018, 10:02:30
**Message** Specified method is not supported.
**Exception type**  System.NotSupportedException
**Failed method**   Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexReaderDisabled.GetDataCurrentlyIndexedToken

**Custom Data**

**0**   https://REDACTED-COLLECT-URL/odata/Contacts/Sitecore.XConnect.Search?%24expand=Identifiers,MergeInfo,ConsentInformation

**LogLevel**    Error
**RenderedMessage** XConnect Exception Filter OnException(), url - "https://REDACTED-COLLECT-URL/odata/Contacts/Sitecore.XConnect.Search?%24expand=Identifiers,MergeInfo,ConsentInformation"
**MessageTemplate** XConnect Exception Filter OnException(), url - {0}
**handledAt**   UserCode
**Application** XConnect

**Call stack**

```
System.NotSupportedException:
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexReaderDisabled.GetDataCurrentlyIndexedToken (Sitecore.Xdb.Collection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexReaderCountersDecorator.GetDataCurrentlyIndexedToken (Sitecore.Xdb.Collection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Repository+<WaitUntilDataBecomesAvailableToSearch>d__11.MoveNext (Sitecore.Xdb.Collection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.RepositoryCountersDecorator+<WaitUntilDataBecomesAvailableToSearch>d__10.MoveNext (Sitecore.Xdb.Collection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Service.RepositorySearchInvoker+<Execute>d__7.MoveNext (Sitecore.XConnect.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.XdbOperationInvoker`1+<Execute>d__2.MoveNext (Sitecore.XConnect, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext+<ExecuteBatchAsyncInternal>d__79.MoveNext (Sitecore.XConnect, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext+<ExecuteBatchAsyncInternal>d__79.MoveNext (Sitecore.XConnect, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext+<SubmitAsync>d__74.MoveNext (Sitecore.XConnect, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Web.Controllers.EntityController`1+<CreateResponse>d__31.MoveNext (Sitecore.XConnect.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions+<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute+<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute+<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute+<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute+<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute+<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute+<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute+<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
```

Comment: I would try de-compiling the code to see what the GetDataCurrentlyIndexedToken() method is trying to do. Can you replicate this locally. If not is there something different in the configs between environments. Are you using azure search or solr?

Comment: Thanks I did do that but unfortunately it was a dead end. We are using Azure Search but it looks like some Solr code was being executed because of the xmls that we had enabled under ContentSearch

Answer (score 1):

It turned out this was caused by a configuration issue - some xml files were enabled on the collect role that shouldn't have been. One important thing to note is that even if the "initialize.xml" is disabled, it doesn't mean that other files in the same directory will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by your Contenemt Management instance pointing at the xConnect collection role, instead of the XConnect Search role.

more info here 
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/sitecore-data-flows-and-processes.html

xConnect Collection
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/collecting-experience-data.html

XConnect Search:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/indexing-and-segmentation.html

Comment: This was the issue for me. We hadn't updated our xConnect connection strings to point at the scaled xConnect instances correctly.